# Javascript validate two textbox

Tags: javascript, html, validation

The code below validate two nameserver textbox. As you can see there is redundancy in the javascript code. `// validate textbox 1` and `// validate textbox 2`. Is there anyway I could just use one script.. you know I just want to use 1 validation function to validate two textbox. I'm sorry for my English I hope you all can understand me. Thank you.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

// validate textbox 1
     function validate_domain(){
       var nameserver1 = document.getElementById('nameserver1').value;
       var domain_array = nameserver1.split('.');

      var domain = domain_array[0];
    //This is reguler expresion for domain validation
      var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9])+[A-Za-z0-9-]+([A-Za-z0-9])$/;

    if(domain == ''){
         alert("Please enter the domain name"); 
         document.getElementsById('nameserver1').focus();
         return false; 
    } 

    if(reg.test(domain) == false){
       alert("Invalid character in domain. Only letters, numbers or hyphens are allowed.");
      document.getElementsById('nameserver1').focus();
       return false;
    }

    }



    // validate textbox 2
     function validate_domain(){
       var nameserver1 = document.getElementById('nameserver1').value;
       var domain_array = nameserver2.split('.');

      var domain = domain_array[0];
    //This is reguler expresion for domain validation
      var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9])+[A-Za-z0-9-]+([A-Za-z0-9])$/;

    if(domain == ''){
         alert("Please enter the domain name"); 
         document.getElementsById('nameserver2').focus();
         return false; 
    } 

    if(reg.test(domain) == false){
       alert("Invalid character in domain. Only letters, numbers or hyphens are allowed.");
      document.getElementsById('nameserver2').focus();
       return false;
    }

    }
    </script>

 <fieldset class="inlineLabels">

            <label for="name">Nameserver 1</label>
            <input type="text" class="textInput" maxlength="255" size="30" value="" id="nameserver1" name="nameserver1">

            <label for="data">Nameserver 2</label>
            <input type="text" class="textInput" maxlength="255" size="30" value="" id="data" name="nameserver2">

        </fieldset>

          <button onclick="validate_domain(); submitForm('page1','directpage.php');" value="Validate" name="btn_validate" type="button" class="positive iconstxt icoPositive"><span>Save</span></button>
```

Comment: Okay, I think i'm finally done messing with my answer now, it should be drop in ready.

Comment: I appreciate everybody help but for times being none of the provided code fully functional for me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well here is another approach:

```
function ValidateDomain(){
    function CheckForBlank(domain, textBox){
        if(domain == ''){
             alert("Please enter the domain name"); 
             document.getElementsById('nameserver1').focus();
             return false; 
        } 
    }
    function CheckForFormat(domain, textBox){
        if(reg.test(domain) == false){
            alert("Invalid character in domain. Only letters, numbers or hyphens are allowed.");
            document.getElementsById('nameserver1').focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
    function GetDomainName(inputId){
        var serverName = document.getElementById(inputId).value,
            domain_array = serverName.split('.');

        return domain_array[0];
    }
    var nameserver1 = GetDomainName('nameserver1'),
        nameserver2 = GetDomainName('nameserver2'),
        nameServerInput1 = document.getElementsById('nameserver1');
        nameServerInput2 = document.getElementsById('nameserver2');

    if (CheckForFormat(nameserver1,nameServerInput1) && CheckForBlank(nameserver1,nameServerInput1) 
        && CheckForFormat(nameserver2,nameServerInput2) && CheckForBlank(nameserver2,nameServerInput2)){
        //This means you are valid
        return {
            name1:nameserver1,
            name2:nameserver2 
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I paste your script and click empty button, alertbox appear but when I filled the textbox with data the variable is not submitted to target pages :(

Comment: You can't just copy and paste what I've written. Where I have `//This means you are valid` you have to do what you need this function to do. Probably return both of the `nameserver` values. You could return something like `{name1:nameserver1, name2:nameserver2}` Check out my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

function validate_domain(){

           validateTextBox('nameserver1');
            validateTextBox('nameserver2');
}

        function validateTextBox(tbName){

               var nameserver1 = document.getElementById(tbName).value;
               var domain_array = nameserver1.split('.');

              var domain = domain_array[0];
            //This is reguler expresion for domain validation
              var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9])+[A-Za-z0-9-]+([A-Za-z0-9])$/;

            if(domain == ''){
                 alert("Please enter the domain name"); 
                 document.getElementsById(tbName).focus();
                 return false; 
            } 

            if(reg.test(domain) == false){
               alert("Invalid character in domain. Only letters, numbers or hyphens are allowed.");
              document.getElementsById(tbName).focus();
               return false;
            }

            }

        }
            </script>
```

Comment: I paste your script and click empty button, unfortunately no alertbox appear :(

Answer (score 1):

Saw this one at work. Played with it at home. Here's a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mN9tt/3/). Yes, it's overly complex, but I detest `alert('annoying pop-up');`.

I commented the source, so you would better understand why I wrote it like that.

[sg522](https://stackoverflow.com/users/894470/sg552): It may not copy/paste into your code **and** work, but I don't know what the rest of your code is. Neither are we here to write your code for you. We are here to help you learn and become a more experienced programmer.

Please let us know if you have questions.

Happy coding!

UPDATE: Modified jsFiddle to work with Opera and Firefox 10.
Neither Opera or Firefox apparently allow `cloneNode` to be called without parameters now.
Opera also apparently does not allow chained variable declarations.

Comment: If I understand correctly I will see the output in `<div id="nameserverInputs"></div>` correct? I test the code with empty input at jsFiddle and it don't work?

Comment: You understand correctly. It works for me in Google Chrome. What browser are you using to test it with?

Comment: It turns out it didn't work for Opera 11.61 and Firefox 10.0 but works with IE 9.0 and Safari 5.1. Is there anyway you could make it cross browser compatible?

Comment: What a shame. I have test your solutions with my app and it works beautifully but it not cross browser compatible.

Comment: Modified jsFiddle to work with Opera and Firefox 10. Neither Opera or Firefox apparently allow `cloneNode` to be called without parameters now. Opera also apparently does not allow chained variable declarations.

Answer (score 0):

Take the id of the element you want to validate as a parameter of your function.

```
// validate textbox
 function validate_domain(serverName){
   var server = document.getElementById(serverName).value;
   var domain_array = server.split('.');

  var domain = domain_array[0];
//This is reguler expresion for domain validation
  var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9])+[A-Za-z0-9-]+([A-Za-z0-9])$/;

if(domain == ''){
     alert("Please enter the domain name"); 
     document.getElementsById(serverName).focus();
     return false; 
} 

if(reg.test(domain) == false){
   alert("Invalid character in domain. Only letters, numbers or hyphens are allowed.");
  document.getElementsById(serverName).focus();
   return false;
}

}
```

Comment: I paste your script and click empty button, unfortunately no alertbox appear :(

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

// validate textbox
     function validate_domain(ele){
       var nameserver = ele.value;
       var domain_array = nameserver.split('.');

      var domain = domain_array[0];
    //This is reguler expresion for domain validation
      var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9])+[A-Za-z0-9-]+([A-Za-z0-9])$/;

    if(domain == ''){
         alert("Please enter the domain name"); 
         ele.focus();
         return false; 
    } 

    if(reg.test(domain) == false){
       alert("Invalid character in domain. Only letters, numbers or hyphens are allowed.");
      ele.focus();
       return false;
    }

    }
    </script>

 <fieldset class="inlineLabels">

            <label for="name">Nameserver 1</label>
            <input type="text" class="textInput" maxlength="255" size="30" value="" id="nameserver1" name="nameserver1">

            <label for="data">Nameserver 2</label>
            <input type="text" class="textInput" maxlength="255" size="30" value="" id="data" name="nameserver2">

        </fieldset>

          <button onclick="validate_domain(document.getElementById('nameserver1')); validate_domain(document.getElementById('nameserver2')); submitForm('page1','directpage.php');" value="Validate" name="btn_validate" type="button" class="positive iconstxt icoPositive"><span>Save</span></button>
```

Comment: I paste your script and click empty button, alertbox appear but when I filled the textbox with data the variable is not submitted to target pages :(

Comment: Well, it must be your submitForm function... Otherwise, you can create a form (it would be better actually), and adding to it `onsubmit="if (!validate_domain(document.getElementById('nameserver1')) || !validate_domain(document.getElementById('nameserver2')) ){return false;}"`

Comment: `<form onsubmit="if (!validate_domain(document.getElementById('nameserver1')) || !validate_domain(document.getElementById('nameserver2')) ){return false;}" method="post" action="dns/dns_ns_wizard_pros.php">
 <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>` Is this OK??

Comment: It's not correct. I try it and the data is still not submitted.